# Multi-tomcat servers deployed on a single Linux server, does each of tomcats has an independent JVM?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, jvm

Today I've encountered a problem during my java job interview as below:

**Multi-tomcat servers deployed on a single Linux server, does each of tomcats have an independent `JVM`?**

I think there is only one JDK installed on a server, there is only one JVM on server, is it right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Each instance runs in its own JVM.

Comment: unless running in a multi-tenanted JVM such as Waratek JVM

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks, learned something new today.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen also rumoured to be included in Java9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, one JDK means one copy of a program on disk.

If you run the `java` program (one component of the JDK) twice, with the first copy remaining in memory while the second copy is also running, you will have two JVMs on the server, both running off the same installed JDK.

As far as your Tomcat goes, it is possible for one Tomcat to host many web applications, or to have one Tomcat per each "user".  You have to inspect the installation and configuration, and perhaps observe the environment directly (if possible) to really know what is going on.  You cannot just look at the number of installed JDKs.

Comment: Note that while each JVM will have its own data structures, they'll share the code segment.

Comment: Appreciated to your answers, thanks!!!!! @Edwin Buck. You are really solved my confusion.

Comment: @BradyChu Glad to be of some help.